# Proper usage of alpha chanel (rgba) on text elements css color property

Tags: css

Is there any objective reason for which you should **not** use rgba values on text elements in css? Example:

```
p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}
```

By objective reasons I mean: accessibility issues, performance, browser support and consistency, etc. not opinion based, such as "I prefer HEX"

Comment: Not all browsers support rgba. See https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: These are really old browser versions @GokulRajK.N.

Comment: @Morpheus Well the newest **released** version of Edge doesn't support it as well: https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba I don't get how you can release a browser where basic attributes like this are not supported... smh

Comment: Only Microsoft can do that :)